# How to return data from a table in a Django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display data from a website in HTML.

I have created a class called `Video` in `models.py` as follows:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField("File Name", max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField("Video Title", max_length=250)
```

The database is migrated and I am able to insert data into it using a Django form. I have checked and there is data in the database.

I have the following code in my HTML template file, but the page is empty when it is displayed, and is showing no data.

```
{% for video in Video %}
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">

        <a href="{{ video.filename }}">{{ video.title }}</a>

    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Why isn't this displaying any data in the rendered HTML page?

Edit:

This is the relevant code from the view:

```
def listvideos(request):
    """Renders the listvideos page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/listvideos.html',

    )
```

Comment: We need to see the view. Are you passing anything called Video to the template?

Comment: oh thanks, i'll update my question, no I'm not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates can only render what you pass to them. You're not sending anything called Video, so you can't iterate over it.

```
return render(
    request,
    'app/listvideos.html',
    {'Video': Video.objects.all()}
)
```

You should consider whether you really want to call your parameter `Video`, though; it should probably be called `videos` both here and in the template.

(And please remove that assertion. For a start, it has no place in production code; and secondly the request will always be an HttpRequest, that is part of the contract for a view.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel that worked perfectly, much appreciated. The assertion was auto generated by VS2017, I'll remove it. What was the assertion doing? I'll check the docs now, but if there's an easy explanation as to why it shouldn't be there it would be great hear.

Comment: Also do you have an updated blog? I'm trying to collect a selection of blogs to read at the moment, but your blog is a little out of date in your bio:)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm not really blogging about Django these days. I don't know why the assertion was inserted, but it simply has no place there.